# Webpack issues (via O'Reilly React book)

Tags: webpack

I'm currently running through the O'Reilly book '[Learning React][1]' and I simply can't get Webpack working. The book slips quickly past this with zero explanation.

Here's my webpack.config.js :

```
module.exports = {
entry: "./src/index.js",
output: {
    path: "/dist/assets",
    filename: "bundle.js"
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader: ['babel-loader'],
            query: {
                presets: ['env', 'stage-0', 'react'],
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

The error returned (after running 'webpack') is as follows:

> Error: options/query cannot be used with loaders (use options for each array item) in {

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

```
npm -v : 6.5.0
webpack -v : 4.29.3
```

Full error message:

```
-----------------------------------------
Error: options/query cannot be used with loaders (use options for each array item) in {
  "test": {},
  "exclude": {},
  "loader": [
    "babel-loader"
  ],
  "query": {
    "presets": [
      "env",
      "stage-0",
      "react"
    ]
  }
}
    at Function.normalizeRule (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuleSet.js:264:10)
    at rules.map (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuleSet.js:110:20)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.normalizeRules (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuleSet.js:109:17)
    at new RuleSet (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuleSet.js:104:24)
    at new NormalModuleFactory (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:115:18)
    at Compiler.createNormalModuleFactory (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:586:31)
    at Compiler.newCompilationParams (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:603:30)
    at Compiler.compile (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:611:23)
    at readRecords.err (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:284:11)
    at Compiler.readRecords (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:479:11)
    at hooks.run.callAsync.err (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:281:10)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at hooks.beforeRun.callAsync.err (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:278:19)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compiler.run (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:275:24)
    at processOptions (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:493:14)
    at yargs.parse (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:498:3)
    at Object.parse (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack-cli\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:567:18)
    at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:206:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:500:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:663:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:156:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3)

-----------------------------------------

  [1]: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/1491954620/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03__o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1
```

Comment: I answered first.  Feel free to choose mine as the right answer since I was first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the attribute `query` with an array of `loader`. Note that the `query` attribute [is deprecated](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleoptions--rulequery) for `options`. You can the syntax [`use`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleuse) instead:

```
{
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              // options
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {
entry: "./src/index.js",
output: {
    path: "/dist/assets",
    filename: "bundle.js"
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['env', 'stage-0', 'react'],
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Try taking babel-loader out of the array.